# JavaScript not working despite being valid in 2 validators

Tags: javascript, css

I posted a question earlier about adding an image URL for a background image as well as a background position and was directed to try using a js object rather than an array. This is the code I am trying to use but it just doesn't. Trying various variations with no success.

```
var imgCount = 15;
var dir = "wp-content/themes/Stoq/home-images/";
var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
var images = Object.create();
images[1] = { file: "1.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[2] = { file: "2.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[3] = { file: "3.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[4] = { file: "4.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[5] = { file: "5.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[6] = { file: "6.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[7] = { file: "7.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[8] = { file: "8.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[9] = { file: "9.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[10] = { file: "10.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[11] = { file: "11.jpeg", bkg: "bottom center" };
images[12] = { file: "12.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[13] = { file: "13.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[14] = { file: "14.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
images[15] = { file: "15.jpeg", bkg: "center" };
document.getElementById("random-bkg-img").style.background = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount].file + ")" + " images[randomCount].bkg ";
```

I have searched for examples and ran JavaScript through validators which don't show any errors. I'm not very good as js so reaching the limit of my abilities here

Comment: FYI, array indexes normally start at 0.

Comment: In what way doesn't this work? Are you getting an error in the console? Why are you using `Object.create()` to create an array when you could just write `var images = [];`?

Comment: `images[randomCount].bkg` should not be in quotes.

Comment: *"despite being valid in 2 validators"* - This is a fairly important lesson.  Code validators can only tell you if the code is **syntactically valid**.  That is, they can tell you whether or not the JavaScript engine will be able to understand the code at all.  They **do not** tell you if the code is logically correct for whatever you intuitively expect it to do.  As the programmer, that part is your job.  Debugging tools are immensely helpful in that regard.  In this case, now is a great time to start familiarizing yourself with the debugging tools in your browser.  (e.g. the script debugger)

Comment: Hi and thanks. Those were the issues that you caught. Made the three changes and now it is working as expected. Thanks very much